# How to convert Pathfinder's sailing rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, conversion

I want to know how I can incorporate sailing into a 5e campaign.  The main problem I'm having is that I can't find any rules for ship sailing or ships themselves anywhere for 5e.  The only rules I have are from Pathfinder, the [skulls and shackles pathfinder adventure](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/ship-combat/advanced-naval-combat) My question is would I be able to bring those Pathfinder rules over to 5e?

Comment: Given that a reasonable answer is "There are already rules", is that good enough or do you still want to convert the rules over to 5e? (maybe you really like it or something)

Comment: No thats is good enough, I was just wondering to be honest

Answer (score 19):

You probably could, but you don't really need to. D&D 5e has rules for sailing on pages 117-119 of the Dungeon Master's Guide.